# How to connect to remote server with proxy in win32 API?

Tags: c, winapi, proxy

```
// try to connect to server
if ((Status = connect(sock_server, &serverSockAddr, sizeof(serverSockAddr))) < 0)
{
    SockSend(sock_client, "404 Host Not Found\n\n", 20);
    SockClose(sock_client);
    return 1;
}

// send client's req to server
SockSend(sock_server, buf, strlen(buf));
```

The above is the code to `connect` to remote server **without** proxy,how can I do it **with** proxy?

Answer (score 0):

The InternetOpen function allows specifying a proxy.  Next the InternetConnect function can be called.  InternetConnect gives you a small selection of server ports to connect to.  I don't see any way to reach an arbitrary port number on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Winsock API for this type of thing is almost never the right choice. Using WinHTTP or WinINET is a much simpler way to go, and will allow you to avoid writing thousands of lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume HTTP proxy.

You connect to the proxy and then issue the GET or whatever HTTP you want to do. You will need to make sure the GET has domain + resource like

```
GET stackoverflow.com/ HTTP/1.0
Host: stackoverflow.com
```

RFC docs for HTTP 1.0 and 1.1 will detail more. For other types of proxies you will need to provide some feedback.